# entering a date for UDF

Tags: excel, vba

So i have created a UDF that is an index match. It works perfectly, but when i change one of my variables to a date i run into issues. I simply cannot type  "oct-18", oct-18 or 01-10-2018. I have to reference a cell that has the date, i assume this is as it linked to the date code 43374 for oct-18. I would like to have both options:

1) Where i can reference a cell
2) where i can simply type the date in such as oct-18

any help or indications of what to do would be great

below is the UDF i have written:

```
Function flatrate(Xa, Aa)
Application.Volatile
Dim lngRowMatch       As Long
Dim lngColMatch       As Long
Dim matrix            As Range

Set matrix = Sheets("flat rates").Range("flat_rates")
With matrix
  lngRowMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Xa, .Columns(1), 0)
  lngColMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Aa, .Rows(1), 0)
  flatrate = .Cells(lngRowMatch, lngColMatch)
End With
Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A string that looks like a date is still not a true date. Try adding date conversion within the function.

```
Function flatrate(Xa as variant, Aa as variant)

    Application.Volatile
    Dim lngRowMatch       As variant
    Dim lngColMatch       As variant

    if isdate(Xa) then _
        Xa = cdate(Xa)    '<~~ force date conversion here

    With workSheets("flat rates").Range("flat_rates")
      lngRowMatch = Application.Match(Xa, .Columns(1), 0)
      lngColMatch = Application.Match(Aa, .Rows(1), 0)
      if iserror(lngRowMatch) or iserror(lngColMatch) then
          flatrate = cverr(xlerrna)
      else
          flatrate = .Cells(lngRowMatch, lngColMatch)
      end if
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: i tried the above, came out with the following vba:

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing `.Cells(lngRowMatch, lngColMatch).value2` to get the actual value of the cell that isn't automatically converted by Excel.